# Have Ubuntu 18.04LTS installed, windows boot can't detect hard disk (possible GRUB issue)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have Ubuntu18.04LTS installed on my laptop. Now I want to install Windows 10 (via bootable usb) but it asks for hard disk driver in the part where hard disk needs to be partitioned. I think it may be related to Grub 2.2 and MBR (or maybe not, I'm not an expert). What can I do to install Windows 10? I'm ok with losing all my data and my Ubuntu.

ps. actually I had Windows 10 on my laptop first. Then I installed Ubuntu but it messed up my Windows and I performed several "boot-repair" actions which did not repair it.

Answer (score 0):

To do it easier, if you don't mind to lose your data, you have to install Win10 first, and then do a partition for Ubuntu.
So, delete Ubuntu, install win10, make a partition and then install ubuntu. Tell me if you solve this

Answer (score 0):

Did you format your drive before installing Ubuntu? It may be because your Windows is booting in UEFI mode and your harddisk is formatted with MBR Partition scheme.

First of all check if the harddisk is being recognized by the BIOS (you didn't say if ubuntu was booting from it or not). If it is being recognized in the bios, boot with the Windows Installation Disk and follow [these](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style#reformatting-the-drive-using-a-different-partition-style) instructions. This will require some use of command prompt.

Comment: Easiest way for dual booting Ubuntu with windows is following path described by @SantyAlvarez

Comment: the hard disk was being recognized by the BIOS and the Ubuntu did boot normally. I had to use the second step in your link and clean my hard drive using cmd.

Comment: Then the hard disk must have had MBR  partition scheme.